# Find Largest Value in one cell and then display a different cell in the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This was a fairly difficult question to put to words but hopefully the example data and my attempt will help

I have the following

```
Apple       17  1    0  0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0       0
Orange      14  1   15  1    6.67   1    6.67   1    6.67   2   13.33   10
Banana      15  3    5  0    0      0    0      0    0      0    0       1
Cherry      13  1   12  2   16.67   2   16.67   2   16.67   2   16.67    2
Peach       16  4   12  1    8.33   1    8.33   2   16.67   2   16.67    8
Strawberry  12  5    6  1   16.67   1   16.67   1   16.67   1   16.67    7
```

I am trying to find the max value in M and then display A from the same row. So in this example the max value would be 10 and "Orange" should be displayed.

It should be noted that I am using 2 sheets, "Data" has my output and "Raw Data" has... the raw data

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX('Raw Data'!M1:M6), A1:M6, 1, FALSE)
```

This produces #N/A and I think it might have something to do with my data either not being formatted into a table (though doing so seems to fail with a different error) or running from one sheet to the other.

Any input would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLOOKUP requires that the value to find is in the first column.

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH(MAX(M1:M6),M1:M6,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(M1:M6),M1:M6,0),1))

Answer (score -1):

I recomend using Index Match as Scott Craner has shown.

But if you are set on using vlookup:

I will first shortly explain vlookup as how I have understood it.

First a limitation, vlookup can only return values to the left of your search range, i.e you cant use negative numbers i.e,

`=vlookup(Max('Raw Data'!M1:M6), A1:M6, **"-1"**, False)`

Secondly, vlookup is structured like this:

=vlookup(The value you want to search for, the range you want to work with, which column you want to return a value from (1 means the first column).

vlookup will allways search for the vale you want to search for in the first column.

So in your data:

You are telling vlookup to search for the maximum value that exists in the range M1:M6. In this case 10 right?

You are telling vlookup to search for this value in column A which contains the fruits. This is where it goes wrong.

My solution to this would be to move all the fruits names to the N column (to the left of you values you want to search).

In code:

In the N Column:

Put = A and the row number

Now do a vlookup like this:

```
=vlookup(Max('Raw Data'!M1:M6), M1:N6, 2, False)
```

I hope this can solve your problem.

Best regards,